# way to fetch column from mysql in Hibernate, Spring mvc web application

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, web-development-server

```
//this query can be used to get list of PaymentAttribute for whicch payment details is NOT NULL
    @Query("select p.paymentDetailName from paymentattribute p  where p.entityId=?1 AND p.entityType=?2 and p.paymentDetailName is not null")
    List<String> getNonNullPaymenyDetaisName(String entityId,String entityType);
```

My paymentattribute table contains some column like entityId, entityType,paymentDetailsName etc. I want to fetch just paymentdetail column as per query stated above . I am getting error. Is there is way in Spring-mvc web applications , via which i can fetch just the column rather than complete tuples. Above code is part of repository.

Comment: What is the exception that are you getting.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: paymentattribute is not mapped [select p.paymentDetailName from paymentattribute p  where p.entityId=?1 AND p.entityType=?2 and p.paymentDetailName is not null]